# Schematic Review: Interfacing ADS1299 with Seeed XAIO NRF52840 sense?

Tags: schematics, ads, review, nrf52832, eeg

I need someone to review my schematic and guide me to fix the problems in the schematics.

1. Need help reviewing the schematics.
2. Can I power the ADS1299 with Seeed Xaio? If not, then how? I asked this on OpenBCI and the mentioned that I would need some filtered power supply
3. I have modified the schematic that I have found online and that one didn't have any crystal in the schematic but most of the ADS1299 schematic feature a crystal. What is the use of it?

I have to tried to read the data sheet for ASD1299 but it was too complex for a beginner like me.

I am attaching the schematic below:

[image]

Comment: 2) and 3) reference products and datasheets that you don't provide. What modifications did you make to the schematic and why?

Comment: See Recommended Operating Conditions and read the datasheet; https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1299-6.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1698770305168&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Feu.mouser.com%252F

Comment: Open input on CLKSEL, not a good idea.